# Sort 2D NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have 2D array Like following:

```
NSMutableArray *world=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSNumber *number;
NSMutableArray *inner;

int scr=2;
number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:scr];
inner=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",number,nil];
[world addObject:inner];

scr=6;
number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:scr];
inner=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"XYZ",number,nil];
[world addObject:inner];

scr=1;
number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:scr];
inner=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"PQR",number,nil];
[world addObject:inner];

scr=5;
number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:scr];
inner=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"DEF",number,nil];
[world addObject:inner];

scr=3;
number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:scr];
inner=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"LMN",number,nil];
[world addObject:inner];
```

Now,I want to Sort the world array to have following result,

```
XYZ 6
DEF 5
LMN 3
ABC 2
PQR 1
```

can anybody please help me,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am using this     NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"number" ascending: NO];
        [world sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

Comment: Are you try with NSSortdescriptor?

Comment: I have tried and it gives me this Error::::'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x45c4> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key number.'

Comment: ok so which line you want sort number or word?

Comment: i want to sort array on Number in descending manner

Comment: ok wait I will provide the solution for that.

Comment: Your welcome wait i just try to find the solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10953/discussion-between-anand-and-vishiphone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sortedArrayUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a) to sort the array by customized sorting code block. Have a try with this:

```
NSArray *sortedWorld = [world sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    NSNumber *numA = [a objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber *numB = [b objectAtIndex:1];
    return [numB compare:numA];
}];
```